# If the vector space dimension of $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/I$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is finite, then $I$ contains a power of $(x,y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, plane-curves

I am trying to understand a proof which goes like this.

> If $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{C}} \ \mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/I$ is finite, then $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/I$ has a finite composition series whose subquotients are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/\mathfrak m$, so $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/I$ is annihilated by a power of $(x,y)$.

Can anyone help me understand this proof?
I shall  be very grateful.

Comment: This seems like an awkward proof to me, so let me suggest a simpler one: if $\dim \Bbb C[[x,y]]/I$ is finite, then $x^m\in I$ and $y^n\in I$ for some $m,n\geq 0$. Then $(x,y)^{m+n}$ acts as zero on $\Bbb C[[x,y]]/I$, since every monomial in $(x,y)^{m+n}$ is divisible by at least one of $x^m$ or $y^n$. Alternatively, you could use the characterization of an Artinian algebra over a field as one with finite vector space dimension, which implies that some power of every ideal is zero.

Comment: Why does  finiteness implies x^m∈I and y^ n∈I

Comment: The set $\{x^k\mid k\geq 0\}\subset \Bbb C[[x,y]]/I$ must be linearly dependent by dimension reasons, so $\sum_{i=0}^d c_ix^i = 0$ in $\Bbb C[[x,y]]/I$, or $\sum_{i=0}^d c_ix^i\in I$. Factoring this as $x^m\cdot p(x)$ where $p(x)$ has nonzero constant term, we see that $p(x)$ is a unit and thus $x^m\in I$.

Comment: Although the OP didn't make it clear, $\mathfrak m$ in the question is $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an $R$-module $M$ has a composition series $(0)=M_0<M_1<\dots<M_n=M$ such that $M_i/M_{i-1}\simeq R/\mathfrak m$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ ($\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$), then $\mathfrak m^nM=0$.

This can be easily proven by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then $M\simeq R/\mathfrak m$, and therefore $\mathfrak mM=0$. Now suppose that $\mathfrak m^{n-1}M_{n-1}=0$. Since $M/M_{n-1}\simeq R/\mathfrak m$ we have $\mathfrak m(M/M_{n-1})=0$, that is, $\mathfrak mM\subseteq M_{n-1}$. Then $\mathfrak m^nM\subseteq\mathfrak m^{n-1}M_{n-1}$ which implies $\mathfrak m^nM=0$.